# time picker dialog not working

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am new in android, and I tried to add time picker dialog to my app to take the time from the user.
but the dialog was not appear. 
I am using android studio.
this is the code:

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
int hour= calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes1= calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
EditText time=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.TimeEdT);
time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog=new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    time.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
                }
            },hour, minutes1, true
            );
            timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

the dialog is not appear when i tried to run the application.
my goal is to take the time from the user and use it as input to text, then use it for alarm notification.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `time` View is an `EditText`.

When you click in an `EditText` it puts the cursor within the text allowing you to edit it, bringing up a soft keyboard if required.

It seems you want to get rid of that functionality and bring up a `TimePickerDialog` instead when you click on it. So if you don't need that extra functionality, just use a `TextView` instead.

Comment: yes thanks, but how can i take this change in alarm ? i mean that after the user set the text it means the alarm set also and when reach the time it gives a notification and ring!

Comment: @NujudAli How to set alarms is a whole separate subject. You should take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html